# To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files - Vagrant/Ubuntu/Magento 2.0.2

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php, magento2

When installing Magento 2.0.2 via composer getting this error:

```
Problem 1
 - Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.0.2].
 - magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.0.2 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:

- /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pspell.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I have installed php5-cli, php5-curl.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Anything unclear about that output?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

First installed `sudo apt-get install php5-gd`, then `sudo apt-get install php5-intl` and last one was `sudo apt-get install php5-xsl`. 
After that, it's installing as it should.

Comment: If you have a newest version of php you must use `apt-cache search php7-*` to find packages and install after. In my case with php7 candidates was: 
`php7.2-gd` `php7.2-intl`and `php7.2-xsl`

Comment: This helped me out                                             https://stackoverflow.com/a/46058582/8090905

Comment: These 2 commands worked for me: `sudo apt-get install php-zip` `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring`

Answer (score 48):

This solved my issues

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

or newer version (* = your php version )

```
sudo apt-get install php7.*-xml
```

Comment: for me  :  sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml

Comment: How can installing an XML extension help if the GD extension is missing?

Comment: Just run this, no headaches later: `sudo apt-get install php7.*-xml`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml` is what I needed to do before using composer to install phpunit9

Comment: B/c of TL;DR I jumped off to @DwayneWalsh tho it's what's written in the actual answer

Answer (score 30):

ubuntu users try this

```
apt-get install php7.2 libapache2-mod-php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-gd php7.2-mysql php7.2-curl php7.2-intl php7.2-xsl php7.2-mbstring php7.2-zip php7.2-bcmath php7.2-soap php-xdebug php-imagick
```

this is work for php 7.2 but you can change this 7.2 to 5.2 and run this command
it is work.

Comment: Thank you. It saves my day.

Answer (score 28):

Have tried for many times, the above answers don't solve my quesiton, but this command helped me:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

Comment: sometime coming down to answer lists in stack overflow is great !
Issue fixed thanks

Answer (score 19):

When I went to create a laravel project, I got this problem.

After googling, I got this solution.

I followed these steps:

Step 1: `sudo apt-get install -y php7.2-gd`

Step 2: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl`

Step 3: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-xsl`

Step 4: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring`

Answer (score 12):

Updated....For ubuntu users

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php php-common php-gd php-mysql php-curl php-intl php-xsl php-mbstring php-zip php-bcmath php-soap php-xdebug php-imagick
```

Answer (score 9):

this command would do the trick

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than the previously suggested ones.

Answer (score 7):

First installed

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

and last one was

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xsl
```

After that, it is installing as it should.

Comment: I did the same as above replacing php5 with php7.2 and it worked like a charm

Comment: I did the same as above replacing php5 with php7.2 and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 6):

@Verse answer works fine. But there is a small thing I would like to add.
instead of installing `php5-mbstring`, `php5-gd`, `php5-intl`, `php5-xsl`. This answer  is based on @Regolith answer: [Package has no installation candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821292/package-php5-gd-has-no-installation-candidate?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) .

Install according to your *php-version*.

First check which php version you have by sudo php -v. I have php7 so the result is:

```
PHP 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
   with Zend OPcache v7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

since i have php7, I will do the following to list the php packages:
`sudo apt-cache search php7-*`

this returned

```
libapache2-mod-php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
php-all-dev - package depending on all supported PHP development packages
php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
php7.0-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
php7.0-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
php7.0-common - documentation, examples and common module for PHP
php7.0-curl - CURL module for PHP
php7.0-dev - Files for PHP7.0 module development
php7.0-gd - GD module for PHP
php7.0-gmp - GMP module for PHP
php7.0-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.0-ldap - LDAP module for PHP
php7.0-mysql - MySQL module for PHP
php7.0-odbc - ODBC module for PHP
php7.0-opcache - Zend OpCache module for PHP
php7.0-pgsql - PostgreSQL module for PHP
php7.0-pspell - pspell module for PHP
php7.0-readline - readline module for PHP
php7.0-recode - recode module for PHP
php7.0-snmp - SNMP module for PHP
php7.0-sqlite3 - SQLite3 module for PHP
php7.0-tidy - tidy module for PHP
php7.0-xml - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
php7.0-xmlrpc - XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP
libphp7.0-embed - HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)
php7.0-bcmath - Bcmath module for PHP
php7.0-bz2 - bzip2 module for PHP
php7.0-enchant - Enchant module for PHP
php7.0-fpm - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
php7.0-imap - IMAP module for PHP
php7.0-interbase - Interbase module for PHP
php7.0-intl - Internationalisation module for PHP
php7.0-mbstring - MBSTRING module for PHP
php7.0-mcrypt - libmcrypt module for PHP
php7.0-phpdbg - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (PHPDBG binary)
php7.0-soap - SOAP module for PHP
php7.0-sybase - Sybase module for PHP
php7.0-xsl - XSL module for PHP (dummy)
php7.0-zip - Zip module for PHP
php7.0-dba - DBA module for PHP
```

now to install packages run the following command with your desired package

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-gd, php7.0-intl, php7.0-xsl, php7.0-mbstring
```

*Note*: `php7.0-mbstring`, `php7.0-gd` `php7.0-intl` `php7.0-xsl` are the package that are listed above.

*UPDATE*:
Don't forget to restart `apache/<your_server>`

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 5):

This was the fix for me when trying to install Laravel on a fresh WSL installation:

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd`

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl`

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-xsl`

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip`

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 16.04 php7 is now the default, so if you follow the top answers and are still having this issue, check your php version.

```
php --version
```

If your default php version is php7, but you followed an answer using php5 packages, you can use the following command to set the default version of php to php5.6:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php $(which php5.6)
```

Answer (score 3):

I used below to fix issue

yum install -y php-intl php-xsl php-opcache php-xml php-mcrypt php-gd php-devel php-mysql  php-mbstring php-bcmath

Answer (score 3):

for similar case:

- /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini

solved with :

```
apt-get install php-dom
apt-get install php-mbstring
```

Answer (score 2):

The exact name of the extension depends on the repository from which you got PHP but look [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html#instgde-prereq-php56-install-centos). For example on CentOS:

`yum install -y php56w php56w-opcache php56w-xml php56w-mcrypt php56w-gd php56w-devel php56w-mysql php56w-intl php56w-mbstring php56w-bcmath`

Comment: I did sudo apt-get -y install php5 php5-mhash php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-cli php5-mysql php5-gd php5-intl php5-xsl php5-bcmath. Getting Unable to locate package php5-bcmath

Comment: `php5-bcmath` may be built-in on some systems. Try exclude that from your install command, and check to see if it's installed afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

For me

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Gonna post this answer here after seeing some of the answers (including the accepted one) which claim to "do the trick". First, we need to identify the issue before fixing it.

> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.

As the above line clearly states, we need to install the extension php-gd.

So, we can go with `sudo apt install php<version>-gd` and it should fix this error unless the system needs more extensions which happens to be the exact case here in the system in question. It needs a couple more extensions php-intl and php-xsl. 
So let it be mbstring or mcrypt, you should install whatever the extensions your system is missing. How can you find what is missing? Just read the error message, it is there.

Answer (score 0):

It helped my case to install the right curl version

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the xampp/php/php.ini file in any editor
2. Search ";extension=php_intl.dll"
3. Remove the starting semicolon ( ; )

Like:
`;extension=php_intl.dll` to `extension=php_intl.dll`

This helped me.

Comment: "magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.0.2 requires ext-gd" - how does your answer resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Installing PHP extensions:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php-gd

sudo apt-get install -y php-intl

sudo apt-get install -y php-xsl

sudo apt-get install -y php-mbstring
```

Answer (score -1):

**I followed these steps:**

steps1: `sudo apt-get install php5-gd`

steps2: `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`

steps3: `sudo apt-get install php5-xsl`

After that, it's installing as it should.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. If the application needs `ext-gd`, your command might resolve problems during the installation itself, but not during the runtime of that application