# Package 'php5-gd' has no installation candidate

Tags: php, linux

"PHP module gd: Missing" I received such an error. and I'm trying to install `php5-gd`.

```
apt-get install php5-gd
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 and PHP version 7. I made all the updates.

When I tried to install `php5-gd`, I got an error like below.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-gd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-gd' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: You can try with php7.0-php

Comment: You have php 7 installed . But trying to install php 5 gd library

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First check which php version you have by `sudo php -v`. I have `php7` so the result is:

```
PHP 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 (cli) (built: Apr 26 2017 23:59:48) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.18-0ubuntu0.17.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

since i have php7, I will do the following to list the php packages

```
sudo apt-cache search php7-*
```

this returned

```
libapache2-mod-php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
php-all-dev - package depending on all supported PHP development packages
php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
php7.0-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
php7.0-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
php7.0-common - documentation, examples and common module for PHP
php7.0-curl - CURL module for PHP
php7.0-dev - Files for PHP7.0 module development
php7.0-gd - GD module for PHP
php7.0-gmp - GMP module for PHP
php7.0-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.0-ldap - LDAP module for PHP
php7.0-mysql - MySQL module for PHP
php7.0-odbc - ODBC module for PHP
php7.0-opcache - Zend OpCache module for PHP
php7.0-pgsql - PostgreSQL module for PHP
php7.0-pspell - pspell module for PHP
php7.0-readline - readline module for PHP
php7.0-recode - recode module for PHP
php7.0-snmp - SNMP module for PHP
php7.0-sqlite3 - SQLite3 module for PHP
php7.0-tidy - tidy module for PHP
php7.0-xml - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
php7.0-xmlrpc - XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP
libphp7.0-embed - HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)
php-amqp - AMQP extension for PHP
php-apcu - APC User Cache for PHP
php-gearman - PHP wrapper to libgearman
php-geoip - GeoIP module for PHP
php-gmagick - Provides a wrapper to the GraphicsMagick library
php-gnupg - PHP wrapper around the gpgme library
php-http - PECL HTTP module for PHP Extended HTTP Support
php-igbinary - igbinary PHP serializer
php-imagick - Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library
php-libsodium - PHP wrapper for the Sodium cryptographic library
php-mailparse - Email message manipulation for PHP
php-memcache - memcache extension module for PHP
php-memcached - memcached extension module for PHP, uses libmemcached
php-mongodb - MongoDB driver for PHP
php-msgpack - PHP extension for interfacing with MessagePack
php-oauth - OAuth 1.0 consumer and provider extension
php-pinba - Pinba module for PHP
...and do on
```

now to install packages run the following command with your desired package

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql php7.0-gd php7.0-curl php7.0-recode
```

note:`php7.0-mysql php7.0-gd php7.0-curl php7.0-recode` are the package that are listed above.

**UPDATE**

dont forget to restart apache `sudo service apache2 reload`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the meta-paclaget `php-gd`, which is an alias of `php7.0-gd`

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check php version and install modules

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

If you want other modules then use this command to get all available modules

```
apt-cache search php5.*
```

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here.
Use RUN rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php in dockerfile

Also you can see here the solution https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Answer (score 1):

you have php7 installed but you are trying to install a package of php5 that is the problem