# ZipArchive class is missing on your server in Ubuntu

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu

In my wordpress dashboard i am getting "ZipArchive class is missing on your server" this error. I already installed PHP 7.0 on my Ubuntu server. How can i solve this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to install zip archive
depending on which version of php you have installed, try the following

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
```

or if you have `php5.6`

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip
```

or if you have `php7`.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

Then restart the server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To install specific package [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821292/package-php5-gd-has-no-installation-candidate/44945833#44945833)

Comment: Using Ubuntu 18.04, with default php package 7.2.10, you just need to use `sudo apt-get install php-zip`

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading to PHP 7, you should make sure to install the PHP 7 versions of you libraries as well. The PPA providing PHP 7 also provides a php7.0-zip package. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

To see additional PHP 7 libraries that are available, run:

```
sudo apt-cache search php7.0-*
```

Refer this url : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-7-0-ziparchive-library-is-missing-or-disabled