# Can't install package via composer: PHP extension zip is missing

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to install laravel installer with the composer on my Ubuntu PC, but I get this error during the installation. `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v1.4.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^1.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v1.4.0, v1.4.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
`
```

The error appears then I use this comment:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Answer (score 328, accepted):

It says that it requires **zip extension**

> laravel/installer v1.4.0 requires ext-zip...

Install using (to install the default version):

```
sudo apt install php-zip
```

Or, if you're running a specific version of PHP:

```
# For php v7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip

# For php v7.1
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip

# For php v7.2
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip

# For php v7.3
sudo apt-get install php7.3-zip

# For php v7.4
sudo apt-get install php7.4-zip
```

Comment: Works perfectly but shouldn't this be in the composer install? It's a dependency manager...missing a dependency. Maybe it was Cannonical that missed the inclusion.

Comment: @TylerChristian, composer install manages PHP dependencies, php7.0-zip is a system package. It can't be solved by composer. Theoretically, it's possible to add hook that installs system package as well, but it will require sudo access, which is REALLY bad practice.

Comment: `requires ext-zip` is a pretty unhelpful message. Should say `requires php-zip or phpX.X-zip` at least.

Comment: for mac os users please user Homebrew instead. You don't need to run brew commands as root.

example : brew install php7.0-zip

Answer (score 55):

FOR MAC USERS with CATALINA

First, install homebrew.
Then, say

```
brew install php@7.3
brew link php@7.3
```

restart the console and run the laravel installer

Comment: The question asks about Ubuntu, not Mac.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer - how does this command resolve the given problem? Is there any problem in simply installing the given extension without installing other programs first?

Comment: addition, `brew link php@7.3` didn't work. It gave me a warning. I needed to force it using `brew link php@7.3 --force`.

Answer (score 23):

On centos 7 I have used:

```
yum install php-pecl-zip
```

because any other solution didn't work for me.

Comment: The question asks about Ubuntu, not CentOS.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. yum install php-zip doesn't work on CentOS 7.

Comment: for specific versions of php use one of the following package names after "yum install": `php54-php-pecl-zip
php55-php-pecl-zip
php56-php-pecl-zip
php70-php-pecl-zip
php71-php-pecl-zip
php72-php-pecl-zip
php73-php-pecl-zip
php74-php-pecl-zip
php80-php-pecl-zip`

Answer (score 19):

For PHP7.1 install this

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're facing this issue with **macOS Catalina**, I recommend these steps:

1. Install Homebrew (if you haven't already done so): head over to [brew.sh](https://brew.sh/) or simply run this command: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Run `brew install php@7.3`
3. Update your $PATH variable to include the newly installed version of php:

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

4. Reload your shell preferences script `$ source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bashrc`
5. Finally, install laravel: `composer global require laravel/installer`

Comment: Before step 4, open a new terminal window, else the new $PATH will not be available.

Comment: The question asks about Ubuntu, not Mac.

Comment: But I got here looking for this error and I'm on OS X Catalina.  This answer is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

For `Ubuntu 16.04`, I have used this command for `PHP7.2` and it worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip
```

Answer (score 5):

Centos 7 with PHP7.2:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php72 install php-pecl-zip
```

Comment: The question asks about Ubuntu, not CentOS.

Answer (score 3):

to know your php version

```
php -v
```

for php 7.3.0

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-zip
```

Comment: I'm getting this error E: Unable to locate package php7.3-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-zip'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-zip'

Answer (score 3):

```
V=`php -v | sed -e '/^PHP/!d' -e 's/.* \([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\).*$/\1/'` \
sudo apt-get install php$V-zip
```

Comment: Please add some comments to explain how your code answers the question in order to improve this answer.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac with Macports,

```
# port install php71-zip
```

Comment: The question asks about Ubuntu, not Mac.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP 7.2 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip
```

Works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

**zip extension is missing**, You can avoid this error by simple running below command, It will take version by default

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
```

In case you need any specific version, You need to mention a specific version of your php, Suppose I need to install `X` version of php-zip then the command will be.

```
sudo apt-get install phpX-zip
```

Replace `X` with your required version, In my case, it is  `X = 7.3`

Answer (score 2):

For macOs users you can use Homebrew instead :

```
# For php v7.0
brew install php@7.0

# For php v7.1
brew install php@7.1

# For php v7.2
brew install php@7.2

# For php v7.3
brew install php@7.3

# For php v7.4
brew install php@7.4
```

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer - how does this list of commands resolve the given problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am using WSL with ubuntu 16.04 LTS version with php 7.3 and laravel 5.7

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-zip
```

Work for me