# Laravel Not install composer error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

[image]

Actually, I don't understand what's the problem going on

[image]

Comment: Your php configuration does not have the php-zip extension enabled. Check for modules in the php.ini file and enable the ones you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install laravel installer via composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058457/cant-install-laravel-installer-via-composer)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the zip extension for php 7 on ubuntu by using the ssh command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

try

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
```

And then you need to restart apache to include this extension:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it requires the `zip extension`.

You can install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip
```

Comment: unable to locate package php7.2-zip