# Cannot install laravel with composer

Tags: laravel, macos

I try to use the following command on my macos terminal,

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

And I get the following error,

```
  Problem 1
- laravel/installer v3.0.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
- laravel/installer v3.0.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
- Installation request for laravel/installer ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v3.0.0, v3.0.1].
```

I have tried the following solution, but that doesn't work for me,
[Can't install laravel installer via composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058457/cant-install-laravel-installer-via-composer)

Comment: have you installed wamp, xamp or lamp on your system

Comment: or simply have you installed php ?

Comment: Check your php extensions in phpinfo

Comment: Please read the Server Requirements for installing Laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x#server-requirements

Comment: Please, give more information about your system: OS, php version, ...

Comment: update your laravel installer and also make sure you have right php-zip extension for your php version.

Comment: I have MAMP on the system. Php version is PHP 7.3.9 and MacOS Catalina

Answer (score -1):

check your php version and update via homebrew

`brew update`

`brew upgrade php`

Comment: hm, strange. last night I setup development environment on mojave os and did't have any issues. I only need to create usr/local/bin/composer folder and setup path in .zshrc to be able to reach global package

Comment: Php version is PHP 7.3.9