# updating php modules or extensions in Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, php-7.2

I am trying install a `laravel` installation via `composer` on `Ubuntu 16.04`, now while doing so I am getting an error:

```
 To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I was having `php-7.0` version and I updated to `php-7.2` version. I did installations to these also:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-fpm php7.2-curl php7.2-mysql php7.2-gd php7.2-xml php7.2-mcrypt php7.2-mbstring php7.2-iconv
```

I guess something is missing for installation.

Help me out with this. Thanks

Comment: Try logout and login. And then google around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815376/to-enable-extensions-verify-that-they-are-enabled-in-those-ini-files-vagrant

Comment: I recommend you use xampp to avoid these kinds of errors.

Comment: have you removed php7.0?

Comment: @RahulShrivastava I have always used ubuntu and I can assure you I have never gotten these errors

Comment: The first few ones are easy. You need to install PDO and mysqlnd  (different from mysql) and enable opcache (I don't think it's enabled by default). Most of the others though are supposed to be extensions which are enabled by default so it's odd that they need enabling. At any rate `phpenmod` might help here

Comment: Read the [server requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#server-requirements) for Laravel and install/enable all those extensions.

Comment: silly note but your install string does not actually install php7.2 only extensions for php 7.2

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.2-cli
```

and so on

```
service nginx restart # or service apache2 restart
```