# To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files - Windows using XAMPP

Tags: php, windows, xampp, composer-php

When I try intall composer, this error shows:

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files

I'm using Xampp in Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the list of required PHP extensions and try to install all.

Check this link also [To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815376/to-enable-extensions-verify-that-they-are-enabled-in-those-ini-files-vagrant)

Comment: he said windows and those article about linux?

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution is to check what extension is it asking to enable, if you see the code carefully, its given their which extension you need to enable.

In my case = **it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.**

So I simply gone to php.ini file and
Search for gd extension.
I got this in my php.ini file.
Simply remove the ; - semicolon from thier.
Restart the apache server(wampp or xampp)

Answer (score 0):

So I simply gone to xampp/php/php.ini file and Search for gd extension. I got this in my php.ini file. Simply remove the ; - semicolon from their. Restart the apache server(wampp or xampp)

Answer (score 0):

i has same issue but i solvet with cammand (`--with-all-dependencies`) for example
`composer require laravel/passport --with-all-dependencies`